# Tomar valor de un campo a partir de un identificador de una tabla

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes instrucciones con la cual pretendo obtener un valor de un campo a partir de un identificador de una tabla.

```
  idFac = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["id"]);//Capturo el Id del registro
         sql.Append("SELECT codigo from factura");//aplico la query
         sql.Append("WHERE id_factura=idFac");
         var registro = db.Database.SqlQuery<factura>(sql.ToString(),idFac);//almaceno la query en la variable registro

   var querycredifact = db.creditoes.Where(s => s.codigo == Convert.ToDecimal(registro)); //intento mostrar lo que hay en la query
   objcre = querycredifact.FirstOrDefault();
```

lo que pretendo hacer es obtener o referenciar el campo `codigo` que seleccionó en la query, de forma que pueda contar con ese valor para indicarle que es el mismo en otra tabla.

//lo que requiero es que `querycredifact` sea igual al valor existente en el campo `codigo`

No se en que estoy fallando!

Comment: estas usando entity framework ? si es asi porque usas una query para acceder a la factura y un linq para acceder a los creditos? porque no tienes mapeada la factura en el dbcontext y la accedes con un where

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de lo que tenes y lo que queres? no queda claro para que haces tantas transformaciones, ni que tiene s, ni nada de todo esto.

Comment: Hola @leandro si, le respondo a su pregunta por que query para factura, basicamente por que no existe una relación entre factura y créditos por  el campo id, la única forma de asemejarlas es por el campo código, que es el mismo entre las dos tablas

Comment: mi objetivo es que a partir del identificador yo pueda obtener el campo codigo y en el linq indicarle que factura.codigo = credito.codigo

Comment: pero que no exista relacion no quiere decir que no puedas armar un linq usando el join, porque veo que estas entiedades se relacionan por el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto

```
idFac = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["id"]);

string sql = "SELECT codigo from factura WHERE id_factura=idFac";
var registro = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql, idFac).FirstOrDefault();

var objcre = db.creditoes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.codigo == registro);
```

como veras para obtener un valor simple no necesitas castear el `SqlQuery` a una factura, sino que lo haces directo a un tipo de dato simple.

Despues en lugar de usar el `Where()`  puedes aplicar el filtro directo a `FirstOrDefault()`

[Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework 6](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Revisa como asignas el parametro, quizas tengas que usar algo como esto:

```
string sql = "SELECT codigo from factura WHERE id_factura=@idFac";
var registro = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql, new SqlParameter("@idFac", idFac)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: De esta manera, logro reducir en parte mi método inicial, pero igualmente de esta manera no logro obtener lo que hay en el campo código de la tabla factura, mi duda es como referencio ese campo

Comment: porque no logras obtener el codigo, obtienes algun mensaje de error ?

Comment: puede ser como asignas el parametro, edito la respuesta a ver si de esa forma funciona